# While loop in Threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to use while loops inside threads for a bigger project. For simplicity I created an easier example to test it, but it doesn`t work.

My goal is to control the thread for the main function and when the variable `go_thread_one` is switched to False the thread should end. At the moment the second thread is not being used and only the first thread print its text.

How can I fix this error?

Below is the simplified version of my code:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

go_thread_one = True


def first_thread():
    while go_thread_one:
        print('Thread 1')
        time.sleep(0.5)


def second_thread():
    print('Thread 2')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Thread(target=first_thread())
    t2 = Thread(target=second_thread())

    t1.daemon = True
    t2.daemon = True

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    time.sleep(2)

    go_thread_one = False

    print("end main Thread")
```

Comment: Do not call the function when passing it to the thread. The thread does that for you when you pass it the function; calling the function executes it in the current thread, blocking it before anything else can run. E.g. use `Thread(target=first_thread)` instead of `Thread(target=first_thread())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is a problem in these lines:

```
t1 = Thread(target=first_thread())
t2 = Thread(target=second_thread())
```

You should pass a callable object to the `Thread`, but instead you call a function and pass its result. So you don't even create a `t1`, but go inside `first_thread` function and loop there forever.

To fix this, change Thread creation to:

```
t1 = Thread(target=first_thread)
t2 = Thread(target=second_thread)
```

Next, the

```
go_thread_one = False
```

will not give a desired effect – main thread will finish after `time.sleep(2)` even without this line.

To deal with it, you can add

```
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: The flag serves to control thread 1, not the main thread. To achieve the desired behavior, the join is not needed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi author said "My goal is to control the thread for the main function and when the variable go_thread_one is switched to False the thread should end." If we remove the `go_thread_one = False` line the thread `t1` will still end (because main thread will exit).